On Android Flutter, how do I play content ignoring the window manager resolution?
I am in a difficult spot where I am unsure if the issue lies in the Android OS from my vendor, or if the issue lies within my Flutter application?
My Android window manager size (from adb shell wm size) is 1920x1080. In the settings of Android, the resolution is 4K, the display reports that it is 4K resolution.
Now when I give this SurfaceView to ExoPlayer or GStreamer, they both render the content at 1080p.
How do I get my content to render at 4K instead of 1080p? Or should my wm size be at 4K resolution assuming that it supports it.
The following does work, but now, I can't use any of Flutter's components.
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(activity);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

activity.getWindow().addContentView(frameLayout, params);
frameLayout.addView(surfaceView);

Here's what I have tried:

I've tried setting the Flutter's activity's window flag to:

_activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_MEDIA);


I've tried Flutter's Hybrid View and Texture View where both did not work.

